# Unable to stop Iterate mediator for next back-end api calls if first call has failed wso2 7.2.0 mi server 4.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

In WSO2 mi server 4.0.0 I'm using an Iterate mediator to iterate over input and need to make a subsequent API call so when I  was trying to add a logic where if the response of the first API call was not successful then the Upcoming backend API calls need to be dropped no need to execute the next thread need to stop Execution and exit the Iterator Mediator.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="Iterator" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property name="isError" scope="operation" type="BOOLEAN" value="false"/>
    <iterate continueParent="true" expression="json-eval($)" sequential="true">
        <target>
            <sequence>
                <log>
                    <property expression="get-property('operation','isError')" name="filter_flag"/>
                </log>
                                <filter regex="false" source="get-property('operation','isError')">
                    <then>
                <property expression="json-eval($.quantity)" name="QUANTITY" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property expression="json-eval($.price)" name="FINAL_PRICE" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property expression="json-eval($.final_price)" name="PRICE" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <script language="js"><![CDATA[var log = mc.getServiceLog();
                    log.info("Logging inside Script Mediator");
                    var value1 = mc.getProperty("FINAL_PRICE");
                var value2 = mc.getProperty("PRICE");
                var divide = value1 / value2;
               log.info("divide   "+divide);
               var formattedNumber = parseFloat(divide.toFixed(2));
                log.info("result   "+formattedNumber);
                log.info("PRICECOMPARE"+value1===divide);
                mc.setProperty("LIST_PRICE", formattedNumber);
               mc.setProperty("PRICECOMPARE",value1===divide);]]></script>
                <filter regex="false" source="boolean($ctx:PRICECOMPARE)">
                    <then>
                        <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                            <format>{&#xd;
      "line_item": {&#xd;
          "quantity": $1,&#xd;
          "list_price": $2,&#xd
        }&#xd;
    }</format>
                            <args>
                                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:QUANTITY"/>
                                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:LIST_PRICE"/>
                                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:PRODUCT_ID"/>
                            </args>
                        </payloadFactory>
                        <endpoint>
                            <http format="soap11" method="GET" uri-template="http://myendpoint/services/GuestIdentityService"/>
                        </endpoint>
                        <property expression="get-property('axis2', 'HTTP_SC')" name="HTTP_STATUS_CODE" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                        <log>
                            <property expression="json-eval($)" name="status"/>
                        </log>
                        <filter xpath="$axis2:HTTP_SC != '200'">
                            <then>
                                <property name="isError" scope="operation" type="BOOLEAN" value="true"/>
                            </then>
                            <else/>
                        </filter>
                    </then>
                    <else/>
                </filter>
            </then>
            <else>
                <drop/>
            </else>
        </filter>
    </sequence>
</target>
</iterate>
<respond/>
</sequence>
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't break out from an Iterate mediator. What you can do is define a global parameter and then update it if something fails within the Iterate flow, and check this flag before every iteration. Take a look at the following example.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/iterate" name="IterateSample" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <property name="isError" scope="operation" type="BOOLEAN" value="false"/>
            <iterate expression="//test" id="123" sequential="true" continueParent="true">
                <target>
                    <sequence>  
                        <filter regex="false" source="get-property('operation','isError')">
                            <then>
                                <log>
                                    <property name="MsG" value="Iterate"/>
                                    <property expression="$body" name="MsG"/>
                                </log>
                                <call blocking="true">
                                    <endpoint>
                                        <http method="get" uri-template="http://demo3365490.mockable.io/hello">
                                            <suspendOnFailure>
                                                <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
                                                <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                                                <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                                                <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                                            </suspendOnFailure>
                                            <markForSuspension>
                                                <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                                            </markForSuspension>
                                        </http>
                                    </endpoint>
                                </call>
                                <filter xpath="$axis2:HTTP_SC != '200'">
                                    <then>
                                        <property name="isError" scope="operation" type="BOOLEAN" value="true"/>
                                    </then>
                                    <else/>
                                </filter>
                            </then>
                            <else>
                            <drop/>
                            </else>
                        </filter>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
            </iterate>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Comment: As per my above code i was already having a filter before calling the endpoint after the endpoint i was tried setting the parameter to change the Boolean but still it was not exiting the flow when i was trying to print the Global parameter  next to iteratorit was still   false but when i was trying to print inside the filter check of ! = 200 there it was setting as true

Comment: @sathishSankarzz Check the sample I shared, please. It's a working sample.

Comment: I've modifed the code as we are using custom connector to call the endpoint will it affect those global parameter to check the filter to drop if iterator fails in case of failed response from first backend api calls

Comment: @sathishSankarzz whats the connector you are using? Aren't you using a call mediator to do a HTTP call?

Comment: In our custom connector  made of Java API-based connectors we are having an  custom template that will internally will be calling the call mediator of Http call

Comment: @sathishSankarzz In your connector where you have the call mediator you need to set the flag `blocking="true"` for this to work. I have the same in my example above.

Comment: when i try to add the blocking="true" in call mediator 
facing an error in my put request 
Unable to sendViaPut to url[ my server Url] org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 404 Error: Not Found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254761/discussion-between-sathish-sankarzz-and-ycr).